# dotnet ef tool not working since vs2017 / netcore1.1

Tags: entity-framework-core

I recently upgraded a project to use efcore 1.1 as well as visual studio 2017 rc. Also using win10.

The `dotnet ef` commands previously worked with no issue, but now they just throw the following errors.

`{path}.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "_EFGetProjectMetadata" does not exist in the project.`

`Couldn't read metadata for project '{path}.csproj'. Ensure the package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' is installed.`

I verified that the tools are installed, ran `dotnet restore`, everything builds/runs fine. It's only the ef tooling that is causing issues.

Inside the `.csproj` file, the following appears.

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools">
      <Version>1.1.0-preview4-final</Version>
    </PackageReference>`

`<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.0.0-msbuild1-final</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: yep, same thing...

Comment: @PavelBiryukov The package-manager console allows EF commands, so thats something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently tracking this issue at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7072. We will keep that thread updated as we diagnose the issue, find workarounds, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use version`1.0.0-msbuild1-final` for the`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` also.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools">
  <Version>1.0.0-msbuild1-final</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

That got things working for me using dotnet core CLI tools 1.0.0-preview3-004056.